Some email not being received, Google Workspace, .eu TLD
Recently, I've had two companies systems send me mail to my Google Workspace email and it has not been received. I can't determine how long this might have been happening for.
It led me to double checking all my DNS settings. Switching my DNS over to Cloudflare to have more control. Raising tickets with Google support.
I'm a bit lost on how to troubleshoot this further. My domain name is a .eu TLD. I guess there is a very slim chance these systems are not allowing .eu TLDs, but that feels highly unlikely.
What steps would you take to investigate why email is not arriving? Google have confirmed the DNS settings are correct. 3rd party DNS tools seem to come back with a green tick. I've searched the Workspace logs.
I've asked the companies if they can share the errors returned but their customer service team say they can't.
Many thanks for any suggestions as I'm a self taught kinda person, keen to learn more to close the knowledge gap.
p.s. Lots of mail is still arriving and sending fine.

In general when specific messages don't arrive in your inbox they got labelled as spam and then dealt with according your organisations policies  or they got rejected in the SMTP transaction and bounce. A proper sender will record/log delivery success and failures and they can investigate from their end, but of course not all senders properly deal with SMTP errors and bounces. The Google workspace admin user(s) may also be able to see spam reports https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491892?hl=en

Thanks for your suggestion. I've checked the logs and spam reports, no signs of the incoming message from one of the companies. It's a Two Factor service email, which I've tested with a different email address and it comes through.

I suppose it's just "Google doing Google things".
Google is known for its unreliable and untransparent anti-spam system, that often classifies perfectly good messages as spam and rejects them. Especially when these messages come from "unusual" domains ("unusual" as considered by Google - there are no well defined criteria) and/or small senders that don't send many messages to Google. The mailing list for mail operators, https://www.mailop.org/ , is just full of reports about mails being mysteriously rejected by Google. Myself I have also expected it multiple times that emails from me were either rejected by Google or delivered to recipient's spam folder (where nobody actually looks). At other times, almost identical messages, even to the same recipients, went through without issues.
Not much can be done about this. Support tickets may or may not help you. The issue can also go away on its own and a few weeks or even days later messages from the same senders can go through. Or it may not. Basically nobody knows what to expect from Google's antispam system. The whole system is "reputation based", with "reputation" of the sender, sending server or domain being something that is very vaguely defined, also something that constantly changes, especially for small senders.
Basically, if you want a mailbox that reliably receives mail, don't host your mail on Google. That's the best advice one can give.
